# Heroku, DJ, rake task logging

Tags: logging, heroku, delayed-job

I have a rake task running in the background using Delayed_Job. When I'm in development, the rake task writes to a rake.log file. But how do I get the log file written to in production?

I am on Cedar at Heroku with a rails 3.1 app. I have the heroku [Logging addon](http://addons.heroku.com/logging) installed, set to Expanded. I am using both 'puts' and 'Rails.logger' in the rake script. heroku logs and logs --tail works beautifully as a logger for the rest of the app, but the only logs for the rake task say that the worker process has started successfully.

The [heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) say that "Anything written to standard out (stdout) or standard error (stderr) is captured into your logs. This means that you can log from anywhere in your application code with a simple puts statement". How can I make this true for code within a delayed job rake task?

Comment: Your question has been asked and answered before. See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195410/log-doesnt-work-in-production-with-delayed-job) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500200/getting-delayed-job-to-log).

Comment: God, so sorry. Search-fu obviously not set to 'high'.

Comment: Actually Steve, I don't believe this has been answered before (at least in the links you've provided). 

The solutions for the links given seem to be either quite flaky, or involve writing to a log file (which you can't do on heroku). 

Here's a few things that bother me about your 'answer':

1. It doesn't actually provide an answer.
2. You've linked to the actual questions rather than the answers you wish to refer to.
3. I don't believe the answers linked to actually provide an answer to this exact question.
4. I feel like I've been led on a goose chase, with no answer to show for it.

Comment: This question has most certainly NOT been answered.  How does one get Rake task output to show up in HEROKU Logs?  @snowangel - since you marked this as answered, can you tell us what you did that worked to write to Heroku logs from a rake-task?